# Facing issues in eclipse ADB server didn't ACK

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this error...and my eclipse in not running any project

```
[2012-08-28 01:35:50 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
[2012-08-28 01:35:50 - adb] * failed to start daemon *
```

this is what i recieve in android console

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Can anyone tell what to do??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try killing adb.exe using your task manager then restarting Eclipse.

If that doesn't work, try adding adb to your CLASSPATH then restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting all your existing AVD's under .android/avd and restart your eclispe.. create a new avd and run you program... This usually works for me when I get this error

Answer (score 2):

Check the path of adb.exe in task manager, maybe it is not the one in SDK path.

Answer (score -1):

go to task manager kill adb.exe process and than restart eclipse.